# Issue with decimal place pixel alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So a fellow StackOverflow-er wrote out some jQuery based Javascript for me a few days ago.

It works, but there's an annoying issue with it and I wondered if anyone could help out.

The JavaScript is calculating a margin for alignment purposes. The value it calculates is is not always an exact pixel, e.g sometimes its 14.4 etc. In Firefox the issue does not exist, but in other browsers such as in Safari or Chrome when the margin is being calculated (as the screen is re-sized) the far right hand side box 'jumps' and never quite stays against the edge of the container.

As I said above, in Firefox it does not 'jump', and this is the effect I was looking for.

Is there anything that could be done to stop this 'jumping' effect or is it completely related to the browsers rendering engine and out of my control? :(

This JSFiddle contains the code/demo : http://jsfiddle.net/m4rGp/1/

**(Try resizing the browser width in Firefox then Safari/Chrome and you will notice the jump on the right)**

Any reply's are really, really appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: interesting problem, I thought it be due to the decimal place -but I wrapped it into a Math.Round() but it didn't seem to help. :-(

Comment: Hmmmm I don't understand what could be causing it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the rendering engine only. There are no decimals in pixel. 1px is the smallest addressable screen element. So before changing the margin add a `Math.round`

```
 $(".barModules li").css('margin-left', Math.round(dynMargin) + "px");
```

yet the bouncing will be there because the element is positioned in such a way that it is bound to its left (reference). When it sees the attribute `margin-right:0`, it tries to activate that one too ... but due to its `margin-left` being set and positioning based on left .... it is bouncing like that. like a `debounced` function call.

If your aim is to get a dynamic margin, then you have to adjust with this, else go for a fixed width page with centered elements and you don't have to worry about overflow problem

Comment: nice one on the margin. +1 from me.

Comment: For future reference: I actually managed to fix this issue by using an absolute position left instead of a margin left. All the browsers now have no issue with the setup.